# Is it mandatory to select Devices as Universal for iPhone apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, review

I am working on an iOS app that needs to run on iphones only. Therefore, on deployment settings, I have selected **Devices** as **iPhone** instead of **Universal** (screenshot below)

[image]

When I went through Apple's [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#hardware-compatibility), I came across the statement: *"iPhone apps should run on iPad whenever possible"* (screenshot below)

[image]

Then, I ran my *sample app* on iPad simulators (10.5 inch and 12.9 inch). Following are the screenshots of the *sample app* running on those simulators.

[image]
[image]

On clicking the resize button at the bottom-right, the screenshots look as below.

[image]
[image]

Is there any possibility of my app being rejected during the review process considering the settings I have set? Or do I need to set the app as ***Universal***?

Comment: No, it's not necessary to deploy your app as universal. There are lot of apps that are for iphone only

Comment: Those screenshots look OK to me; If your app is iPhone only then that is how it is expected to look on an iPad

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple Guideline Your iPhone app should run successfully on an iPad as well but it will be presented with a scaled screen (letter box view).

Only if you are using any device specific capabilities `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`  then you have to mention that one in `info.plist` file. So that your app will be visible only for iPhone and NOT iPad on App Store like `WhatsApp` app.